# byte array manipulation in arduino

Tags: arrays, arduino, byte

i have two byte array like this

```
byte digitLeftZero[8] = {0b0000,0b0110,0b1001,0b1001,0b1001,0b0110,0b0000,0b0000};
byte digitRightZero[8] = {0b0000,0b0110,0b1001,0b1001,0b1001,0b0110,0b0000,0b0000};
```

and i want to merge them as

```
byte digitDoubleZero[8] = {0b00000000,0b01100110,0b10011001,0b10011001,0b10011001,0b01000110,0b00000000,0b00000000};
```

it is basically took first element of first array 0b0000 and first element of second array 0b0000 and them merge them. 0b00000000.

i have no idea about how to manipulate arrays in arduino

Answer (score 1):

you can use bitwise operators, in particular Bitshiftleft "<<" and than Bitwiseor "|".

Fron Arduino documentation:

Bitshiftleft
"... The left shift operator << causes the bits of the left operand to be shifted left by the number of positions specified by the right operand. ..."

Bitwiseor
"... The bitwise OR operator in C++ is the vertical bar symbol, |. Like the & operator, | operates independently each bit in its two surrounding integer expressions, but what it does is different (of course). The bitwise OR of two bits is 1 if either or both of the input bits is 1, otherwise it is 0. ..."

The type of the variable have to be changed from byte to int, but beware that You have to choose between int or unsigned int based on your needs.
An int represented as binary has the highest value (most left) used to define if the number is negative or positive.

You can start from something like this:

```
byte digitLeftZero[8] = {0b0000, 0b0110, 0b1001, 0b1001, 0b1001, 0b0110, 0b0000, 0b0000};
byte digitRightZero[8] = {0b0000, 0b0110, 0b1001, 0b1001, 0b1001, 0b0110, 0b0000, 0b0000};
byte digitDoubleZero[8] ;

byte a = 0 ;
byte b = 0 ;
byte c = 0 ;


void setup() {

  // open the serial port at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Loop through arrays
  for (byte i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {

    a = digitLeftZero[2] ;
    b = digitRightZero[2] ;

    // debug
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" - ") ;
    Serial.print(a, BIN);  // print as an ASCII-encoded binary
    Serial.print(" - ") ;
    Serial.print(a << 4, BIN) ;
    Serial.print(" - ") ;

    c = a << 4 | b ;

    // output as binary representation
    Serial.println(c, BIN);  // print as an ASCII-encoded binary

    // assign values to target array
    digitDoubleZero[i] = c ;
  }
}

void loop() {

}
```

There is a tutorial in Arduino website that can be useful.
"Bit math with Arduino" https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/programming/bit-math